# How do I show actions based on record conditions in ExtJS grids?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I tried this:

```
renderer : function( strValue, oMetaData, oRecord ) {
  var i;
  if( oRecord.data.leaf )
  {
    for( i in this.items )
    {
      this.items[i].disable();
    }
  }
}
```

But it disabled the actions for the whole column and not just the specific record which was a leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `this` reference is the problem, it seems to contains the wrong scope for what you archive. Take a look at renderer arguments, specially the meta Information.

Comment: I now put the css attribute `display: none;` into the meta-data, which works. Thank you!